# Install CyanogenMod in lenovo A3500-HV

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat

I own a Lenovo [A3500 -HV](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a7_50_a3500-6280.php). I have been using it for an year now and it is running KitKat(4.4.2). There is no sign of a newer OS coming to this tab so I have decided to install a new ROM. I decided to go with CynanogenMod but the problem is my device is not listed in the supported devices directory.
I think my device has the minimum requirements to run the OS.

I would like to know if it will be better to install the CyanogenMod or just leave it with kitkat or maybe install some other mods that my tab can support?

Comment: Not all available ROMs are listed as being "official". Have you checked in the corresponding sections of [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)? That's usually a good source for things like that – especially as you get the user-feedback along and thus know in advance what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably looked only at the official builds, go try to search for an unofficial one. If you don't find one, it's better (and your only choice, if you flash a ROM for a wrong device you are going to break your phone) to stay with your old OS. However, you might still want to root it, as that gives you some new interesting options to explore, too.

But, if you either flash a new ROM or want to root your phone, always do a full backup of your system before doing anything! If something goes wrong, the Backup will save your life.

Comment: I thought flashing the ROM was the only thing I get to do after rooting the phone.. What other features do I unlock by rooting?

Comment: @NirmalRaj You can install system tools like Xposed to customize your current system. Also, some apps require your phone to be rooted to be used, for example a firewall or tethering software. Something I recommend you to do is installing an app called XPrivacy (you can find an app to help you installing it on the Play Store) - it gives you the possibility to manage the permissions for each app, you don't need to grant all permissions to install an app, instead you can choose specifically what you want and there are many more things you can do - just have a look at the XDA Developer forum

Comment: The minimum comment length is just too short ;) I also recommend you to have a look at the different Xposed modules (mods for your system that can be installed via Xposed) - you'll find something useful for you